# Can all steps in feature file of cucumber be reusable across all feature files?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Can all steps in feature file of cucumber be reusable across all feature files?

Since each step phrase should be unique can it be reused across all feature files.

If not, Why it should not be?

Comment: Yes. See [Reusable steps](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/06/09/reusable-cucumber-steps). Also, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  The first step is "Search and Research" before asking. It will help you write questions that get answers.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby Cucumber this is the default. A step defined anywhere in features/step_definitions can be used in any feature. Cucumber will detect when there is more than one step that matches and warn you about it.

In java things should be the same but inevitably the implementation is more complex. As I don't use java I'm afraid I don't know the details of how this is achieved.

Comment: As Java doesn't have the concept of a "World" like Ruby does, this is accomplished by using Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, step definitions **are** shared between features:

"Step definitions aren’t linked to a particular feature file or scenario. The file, class or package name of a step definition does not affect what Gherkin steps it will match. The only thing that matters is the step definition’s expression."
(Source: the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/step-definitions/#scope))

In my opinion, this is one of the major benefits of using Cucumber.

In fact, using feature-coupled step definitions is considered an anti-pattern:

"Feature-coupled step definitions are step definitions that can’t be reused across features or scenarios.
This may lead to an explosion of step definitions, code duplication, and high maintenance costs."
(Source: the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/anti-patterns/#feature-coupled-step-definitions))